# python group list by timestamp

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

Here two sublist of data are there,Please help me on grouping this by timestamp with corresponding data

**code i tried**:(John Galt helped me on this)

```
flat = [y for x in L for y in x]    # L is the list 
[x[0] for x in flat] + [x[1] for x in flat]
[x[0] for x in L[0]] + [y[1] for x in L for y in x]

 [[('2017-08-08 10:00:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 10:05:38', 8.0), ('2017-08-08 10:10:38', 7.5), ('2017-08-08 10:15:38', 8.3), ('2017-08-08 10:20:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 10:25:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 10:30:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 10:35:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 10:40:38', 55.0), ('2017-08-08 10:45:38', 85.0), ('2017-08-08 10:50:38', 55.0), ('2017-08-08 10:55:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 11:00:38', 53.0)], 
        [('2017-08-08 10:00:38', 11.2), ('2017-08-08 10:05:38', 10.0), ('2017-08-08 10:10:38', 13.0), ('2017-08-08 10:15:38', 101.0), ('2017-08-08 10:25:38', 10.0), ('2017-08-08 10:30:38', 10.0), ('2017-08-08 10:35:38', 110.0), ('2017-08-08 10:45:38', 100.5), ('2017-08-08 10:50:38', 100.5), ('2017-08-08 10:55:38', 10.05), ('2017-08-08 11:00:38', 10.10)]]
```

**Desired output:**

```
['2017-08-08 10:00:38','5.0','10.0'],['2017-08-08 10:05:38','25.0','30.0'],['2017-08-08 10:15:38','25.0','35.0']
```

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: i have updated the question

Comment: What's the problem of current code?

Comment: current code results like this [(a, x0), (b, y0), (c, z0)] and [(a, x1), (b, y1), (c, z1)]  but i am expecting like this [[a, x0,x1], [b, y0,y1], [c, z0,z1]]  ..where a,b,c are nothing but timestamps

Comment: If not clear please let me know,i will explain in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
big_list = [[('2017-08-08 10:00:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 10:05:38', 8.0), ('2017-08-08 10:10:38', 7.5), ('2017-08-08 10:15:38', 8.3), ('2017-08-08 10:20:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 10:25:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 10:30:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 10:35:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 10:40:38', 55.0), ('2017-08-08 10:45:38', 85.0), ('2017-08-08 10:50:38', 55.0),('2017-08-08 10:55:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 11:00:38', 53.0)], [('2017-08-08 10:00:38', 11.2), ('2017-08-08 10:05:38', 10.0), ('2017-08-08 10:10:38', 13.0), ('2017-08-08 10:15:38', 101.0), ('2017-08-08 10:25:38', 10.0), ('2017-08-08 10:30:38', 10.0), ('2017-08-08 10:35:38', 110.0), ('2017-08-08 10:45:38', 100.5), ('2017-08-08 10:50:38', 100.5), ('2017-08-08 10:55:38', 10.05), ('2017-08-08 11:00:38', 10.10)]]

big_dict = {}  

for small_list in big_list:  
    for element in small_list:
        if big_dict.has_key(element[0]):
            big_dict[element[0]].append(element[1])
        else:
            big_dict[element[0]] = list()
            big_dict[element[0]].append(element[1])

final_list = list()
for dict_item in big_dict.items():
    local_list = [dict_item[0]]
    for list_item in dict_item[1]:
        local_list.append(str(list_item))

    final_list.append(local_list)
print final_list
```

Comment: that's fantastic !Its works for me.I will accept this answer.But incase if that list is dynmaically changing (ex now it is two list - first and second) and my scenario list size may vary from one to max five ..how to handle?

Comment: thanks!It works.Having one more small clarification . why timestamp is not in ordered format?When i implement this code i am getting this result **ordered result from db**  `[('2017-08-17 12:56:59', 10.366465796627999), ('2017-08-17 12:57:48', 19.19), ('2017-08-17 12:58:51', 0.05)]`  **final_list** `[{'2017-08-17 12:56:59': 10.366465796627999, '2017-08-17 12:58:51': 0.05, '2017-08-17 12:57:48': 19.19}]`

Answer (score 0):

Flattening the list was a good idea, I continued from that point and use `defaultdict` which is a tool worth looking at, look at the result of dictionary `d`:

```
big_list = [[('2017-08-08 10:00:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 10:05:38', 8.0), ('2017-08-08 10:10:38', 7.5), ('2017-08-08 10:15:38', 8.3), ('2017-08-08 10:20:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 10:25:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 10:30:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 10:35:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 10:40:38', 55.0), ('2017-08-08 10:45:38', 85.0), ('2017-08-08 10:50:38', 55.0),('2017-08-08 10:55:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 11:00:38', 53.0)], [('2017-08-08 10:00:38', 11.2), ('2017-08-08 10:05:38', 10.0), ('2017-08-08 10:10:38', 13.0), ('2017-08-08 10:15:38', 101.0), ('2017-08-08 10:25:38', 10.0), ('2017-08-08 10:30:38', 10.0), ('2017-08-08 10:35:38', 110.0), ('2017-08-08 10:45:38', 100.5), ('2017-08-08 10:50:38', 100.5), ('2017-08-08 10:55:38', 10.05), ('2017-08-08 11:00:38', 10.10)]]

flat = [y for x in big_list for y in x]

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, val in flat: # k is the key and val the value of dictionary d
    d[k] += [val]   # the += sign works because each new key have a corresponding 
                    # value automatically initialized to an empty list. 
                    # val is added to that empty list

final_list = [ [k]+[str(val) for val in l] for k,l in d.items() ]

print(final_list)
print(d)
```